# Animating between colors with a gradient in Objective-C using CoreGraphics?

Tags: objective-c, animation, uiview, colors, core-graphics

okay, so I'm doing this to animate through a series of colors for an iOS app:

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:3.0 animations:^{
                gradient = CGGradientCreateWithColorComponents(colorSpace, colors, locations, number_of_locations);
                CGContextDrawRadialGradient(context, gradient, start, 0, end, sqrt((self.frame.size.width*self.frame.size.width)+(self.frame.size.height*self.frame.size.height)), kCGGradientDrawsBeforeStartLocation); 
        }];
```

It works, for the most part. Each time I change a color it flickers with a completely opposite color. For example, when it's about to turn orange from red, it flickers with green.
Community, how fix? :D

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a CAGradientLayer instead. The `colors` property is animatable.

The code you are using above isn't changing any animatable properties, and is a little lacking in context (pun intended) so I'm not sure how it is "working" - it doesn't look like a valid animation block.

Comment: I know, I originally just intended it as a test, considering I had no idea if it would work or not. Thank you!